# Extracting values in a matrix based on values of another matrix without a for loop in Octave

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, octave, vectorization

I'd like to know if there's a way to operate on the values of one matrix, based separatedly on the values of each row from another matrix, without using a `for` loop.

One specific example below.

`data` is a ~500k row matrix with three columns: the first is a list of hours/dates (I have them as serial numbers) covering 24 hours a day for several years, the second column is a location ID, and the third one is the electricity cost in that location.

`hours` has two columns: the first one is a list of dates/hours as a serial number and the second one is a certain upper limit specific for that hour.

What I need to do is find, for every date and hour in `hours`, the largest value of electrical cost that is below the upper limit set in `hours`, and save the ID of the corresponding location in a third column of `hours` if the `id` is unique, or zero if there's no location that satisfy the condition or if there's more than one.

A symplified version of the code I'm using:

```
#Add a third column for the hours matrix
ids=zeros(rows(hours),1)
hours=horzcat(hours,ids)


for i=1:rows(hour)
  #Get the data for all locations in that hour
  idx=(data(:,1)==hour(i,1) )   
  hourlydata=(data(idx,:))        

  #Get the ID for the maximum below the limit in that hour
  idx=(hourlydata(:,3)<hour(i,2))
  idlimit=(hourlydata(idx,3)==max(hourlydata(idx,3))   

  dataid=hourlydata(idlimit,2)

  #Check if the data exists and is unique
  if(rows(dataid)==1)
     id=dataid(1,1)
  else
     id=0
  endif  

  #Save the ID
  hour(i,3)=id
endfor
```

Is there any way to do this without using the `for` loop?

(I already optimized the `data` matrix to make it as small as possible, but it's still pretty big, so I might encounter memory constraints when trying to implement a solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with arrayfun. Suppose your data is

```
data = [datenum('2014-01-17'), 1, 13;datenum('2014-01-18'), 2, 7]
hours = [datenum('2014-01-17'), 17; datenum('2014-01-18'), 3]
```

Then define a selector function

```
function id = select( d, limit, data )
  idx = (data(:,1)==d );

  hourlydata = (data(idx,:));

  idx = (hourlydata(:,3)<limit);
  idlimit = (hourlydata(idx,3)==max(hourlydata(idx,3)));   

  dataid=hourlydata(idlimit,2);

  if length(dataid)==1
     id=dataid(1,1)
  else
     id=0
  end

end
```

Now we find a vector the same size as hours containing the id

```
arrayfun(@(d, limit) select(d, limit, data), hours(:,1), hours(:,2))
ans =
 1
 0
```

You can easily merge this vector with hours.

Now i doubt that this is much faster, but no loop. Works with MATLAB, haven't checked with Octave.